# Python code in Field Calculator gives General error executing calculator ERROR 999999: Error executing function?

Tags: python, arcgis-desktop, field-calculator

In a shapefile, I have Field named ***Elevation*** with a text field containing integer ranges stored as strings:

***1 - 2***
***3 - 6***
***2 - 3***
***8.5 - 12***
***11 - 12***

I need to categorize it using rule that 
if 
Elevation < 1 then Index = 0.3 ,if Elevation = 2 - 3 Index = 0.6, if Elevation > 3 Index = 1

I use this code :

```
def Reclass( Elevation ):
    r_min, r_max = (float(s.strip()) for s in Elevation.split('-'))
    if r_min < 1 and r_max < 1:
        return 0.333
    elif r_min >= 1 and r_max >= 1 and r_min <= 3 and r_max <= 3:
        return 0.666
    elif r_min > 3 and r_max > 3:
        return 1
    elif r_min <= 3 and r_max > 3:
        return 1
    else:
        return 999
```

error log :

```
General error executing calculator.
ERROR 999999: Error executing function.
Expected ')'
Failed to execute (CalculateField).
Failed at Mon Feb 10 10:31:00 2014 (Elapsed Time: 0,01 seconds)
```

Shape : https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzTrGTReNp4mREk1UUEyYzh0TTA/edit?usp=sharing

If I run that code in python window it runs perfectly but gets error in field calculator. how to fix that code in field calculator based on error log?

Comment: I don't think strip is the function you want there

Comment: strip is the function I need, It's work like I Want. Thank You

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not use `print` statements in the code block. `print` expects there to be a terminal to write to, and there is no such terminal inside of Calculate Field.

Comment: Still not working, can you give me sample code?

Comment: @RikudoPain If this advice did not resolve it then can you edit your question to remove the print statement, confirm that the error is still the same, and include details of the precise settings you have on your Calculate Field dialog when this occurs, please?  Knowing your Code Block is important but we also need to know that you are using the Python Parser and what you have set your expression to, and what format your table is stored in (e.g. file geodatabase, DBF, or something else).

Comment: Update Question, including shapefile I want to change.

Comment: "include details of the precise settings you have on your Calculate Field dialog when this occurs, please?"

Comment: It's Already Working, the problem is, when I changed something in the script ArcGIS change the Type to VBS, I need to Change it again twice to Python in Field Calculator and It's DONE!!
Thank You.